# How to read first n-th files from directory (pleaso NOT a "head -n solution")?

Tags: bash, find, ls, head, tail

I have a directory with more then 60000 files. How to get only N of them without using a `find | head -n` or `ls | head -n` solutions, since `find` and `ls` to read this list of files takes too much time. Are there any configs for `ls` and `find` or are there any other programs, which can help to safe the time?

Comment: _"find and ls to read this list of files takes too much time"_ How long does that take? 60000 files isn't that much. On my system `ls | head -n ... | tail -n ...` takes much less than 1s. We probably lack some informations here: do you use a network FS? Or did you have some _critical_ timing requirement? Something else?

Comment: Can you provide timing requirements and how long what you've tried has ran. As written the question doesn't really make much sense since the output of both `ls` and `find` will be line buffered across a pipe and you're not going to get a piped solution much faster than `| head -n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it worth:

```
# Create 60000 files
sh$ for i in {0..100}; do
    for j in {0..600}; do
        touch $(printf "%05d" $(($i+$j*100)));
    done;
done
```

On Linux Debian Wheezy x86_64 w/ext4 file system:

```
sh$ time bash -c 'ls | head -n 50000 | tail -10'
49990
49991
49992
49993
49994
49995
49996
49997
49998
49999

real    0m0.248s
user    0m0.212s
sys 0m0.024s
```

```
sh$ time bash -c 'ls -f | head -n 50000 | tail -10'
27235
02491
55530
44435
24255
47247
16033
45447
18434
35303

real    0m0.051s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.028s
```

```
sh$ time bash -c 'find | head -n 50000 | tail -10'
./02491
./55530
./44435
./24255
./47247
./16033
./45447
./18434
./35303
./07658

real    0m0.051s
user    0m0.024s
sys 0m0.024s
```

```
sh$ time bash -c 'ls -f | sed -n 49990,50000p'
30950
27235
02491
55530
44435
24255
47247
16033
45447
18434
35303

real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.032s
sys 0m0.016s
```

Of course, the following two are faster, as they only take the *first* entries (and they interrupt the pair process with a *broken pipe* once the required "lines" have been read):

```
sh$ time bash -c 'ls -f | sed 1000q >/dev/null'

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
```

```
sh$ time bash -c 'ls -f | head -1000>/dev/null'

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Interestingly enough (?) with `sed` we spend our time in user space process, whereas with `head` it is in sys. After several runs, the results are consistent...

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own simple utility in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *ent;
  int i = 0, n = 0;
  n = atoi(argv[2]);
  dir = opendir(argv[1]);
  while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 ||
        strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0)
      continue;
    if (i++ >= n) break;
    printf("%s\n", ent->d_name);
  }
  closedir(dir);
  return 0;
}
```

This is just a quick and dirty first draft, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is probably not going to be faster than `find | head`. Can you provide timings?

Comment: @tripleee If it concerns you, time it yourself. I don't see how running two programs with a pipe would be faster than a single program. However, I also understand that `find|head` should be good enough. The point is that the above program is simple and quick to write.

Comment: Okay, "hardly a lot faster". My thinking is that the overhead is in the system's `readdir()` ans that you cannot work around that bottleneck by going to bare C, but since you already wrote the code, it would be interesting to hear if my conjecture holds. But I'm not planning to do a measurement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` with `q`:

```
find ... | sed 10q  ## Prints 1st to 10th line.
```

That would make `sed` exit after 10th line which probably could make `find` end its function quicker.

Another way is to use `awk` but `sed` is still more efficient:

```
find ... | awk 'NR==11{exit}1'
```

Or

```
find ... | awk '1;NR==10{exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -f directory | sed -n 1,10p       # print line 1-10
```

Option of `ls`:

`-f`: do not sort

Comment: Depending on implementation this may still allow `find` to continue after 10th line even if `sed` no longer prints its outputs.

Comment: With your `sed 10q` it is much faster than `sed -n 1,10p`. `ls -f` is faster than `find`. Tested with 60.000 copies of /etc/passwd in one dir. Tested wih Ubuntu.