# How to read n files from directory in Python?

Tags: bash, python-3.x, directory, pyqt5

I'm doing a PyQT5 application that needs to select the given folder, and list all the files and directories in it.

To fetch the path, I use simple method that looks like:

```
def open_path():
    dialog = QFileDialog()
    folder_path = dialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Folder")
    return folder_path
```

**EDIT**

This is how I fetch the roots, dirs, and files

```
import os

# this is where I have my open_path() method defined, so I don't write it again

path = str(open_path())
roots = next(os.walkpath(path))[0]
dirs = next(os.walkpath(path))[1]
files = next(os.walkpath(path))[2]
```

I have a folder that contains around 11000 files. I use QFileDialog to fetch the folder, and split it into the 3 lists (roots, dirs, files), and use QDir to display it.

Because of its size, I want to limit the QDir display only first 1000 files, with possibility to load more, after reaching 1000.

Is this possible to do and how?

I couldn't find any documentation or example on how to implement this kind of filter.

I was searching for this info everywhere on the web, but only found this solution -> [How to read first n-th files from directory (pleaso NOT a "head -n solution")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723689/how-to-read-first-n-th-files-from-directory-pleaso-not-a-head-n-solution)
which involves the bash scripting?

I want to avoid using Popen, and PIPE if possible.

Any help or tip is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: This makes no sense: the `getExistingDirectory` function only displays *directories*, not files. And what has the `os.walkpath` code got to do with displaying files in `QFileDialog`?

Comment: @ekhumoro sorry. It was a typo. I have updated the question. Basically I want to use QFileDialog to fetch the path, split the path into 3 lists, and use QDir to display the files only.

Comment: It still makes no sense: you cannot display anything in a `QDir`. Instead of attempting to describe things, please post some real, working code that demonstrates the problem. 11000 items is not a particularly large number to display in one of Qt's view classes.

Comment: @ekhumoro - sorry for the late reply. I actually hit the wall before seeing your reply, and you were right. I ended up with using QDir to get the current working dir, and used the os.walk to go through the directory. I used print function only to spit out the contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  parent_list = os.listdir("Here goes the path for directory")
  count =0
  for child in parent_list:
   if count < 1000:
      print(child)
   else
       break
   count = count+1
```

Here parent_list contains all the file in the given directory, and you can access the first 1000 files in the list using loop. child is the file in the directory

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the list of first n files

```
import os
os.listdir(file_path)[:n]
```